# upper and lower case issue

Tags: magento

We have stock keeping unit with upper and lower case letters like 'AaFa' and 'aAfA' both are two different sku's but magento consider both sku's as same. To overcome this I need to replace small 'a' with 01 and 'b' with 02 and so on. Find and replace is one type of solution, is there any way to get the same functionality with little ease or any code which can do same.

Answer (score 3):

Change `catalog_product_entity.sku` column encoding to case sensitive.